# Why am I getting unchecked runtim.lastError

Tags: reactjs, testing

I'm getting a lot of

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

errors.

Sometimes it's around 1000 of those.

I don't understand what it tells me. How can I report this or find some reproduction steps?

The website is built on React.

Comment: Did you try to search for the problem online? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/lastError

Comment: I'm still learning how to ask good questions (sorry) and how to dig pieces of information on my own

Comment: Does your app utilise any APIs? Care to share the source code?

Comment: I don't have access to the source code but I talked with the devs about it and I'll try to catch some repro, we can close this question, thanks for the help anyway.